# Is there a way to make .next() return to the first item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to make .next() return to the first item? Currently, it cycles through perfectly, however, upon reaching item three, it obviously doesn't have a 'next' to go to. Is there a way to return to item one and loop through again?

```
<div class="item">Item1</div>
<div class="item">Item2</div>
<div class="item">Item3</div>

setInterval(function(){
 $('.item:visible').hide().next().fadeIn('fast');
},5000); //Milliseconds
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this :

```
(function(){
   var i = 1, items = $('.item');
   setInterval(function(){
      items.hide().eq(i).fadeIn('fast');
      i = (i+1)%items.length;
   },5000); //Milliseconds
})();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/mubux/1/edit)

Comment: Hi Dystroy - Thanks a bunch for this. This is fantastic. The only issue I have is that on load, it seems to refresh the first item before beginning it's first loop. So on page load, item one will display, five seconds later, it refreshes and displays item one again before progressing. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FmHsb

Comment: It's probably due to my "$('.image:first').show()" at the very top which I've added to display the first item on page load.

Comment: All fixed. I modified this: var i = 0, image = $('.image'); to this var i = 1, image = $('.image');. Seems to work, although I don't fully understand it! haha.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var cache;

setInterval(function(){
 cache = $('.item:visible').hide().next();
 (cache.length)? cache.fadeIn('fast') : $('.item:first').fadeIn('fast');
},5000);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4g7W7/4/)